# Spring Rsocket Bi-Directional Channel

Tags: spring, rsocket

Is there a possibility to send Messages in a sequential way like flatMapSequential from client to Server? The default behaviour seems to be only in an almost sequential way like flatMap if I use

```java
requester.route("name")
         .data(fluxSendToServer.doOnNext(nr -> log.trace("Send next " + nr.getRequest().getCurrentSequenceValue())))
         .retrieveFlux(ResponseMessageWrapper.class)
```

and log the sequence at the server.

Comment: any extra code to clarify what you mean? So far, the code snippet you shown works sequentially

Comment: +1 to above comment.  this should map to a channel operation. The data you provide can be structured however you want.  You can specifically use flatMapSequential to guarantee it behaves like flatMapSequential before calling data().

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. If I change the Code at the client to

```
  requester.route("name").data(fluxSendToServer.index().map(indexedTuple->{
if(!indexedTuple.getT2().getRequest().getCurrentSequenceValue().equals(indexedTuple.getT1()+1))
{
throw new IllegalStateException("Orderingproblem in client at index "+indexedTuple.getT1());
 };
return indexedTuple.getT2();
 }))
```

and use the same code at the receiving server method

```
     @MessageMapping("name")
   Flux<EncryptedResponseMessageWrapper> handleMessageClientToServer(Flux<EncryptedRequestMessageWrapper> 
         fluxReceivedAtServer){
         return fluxReceivedAtServer.index().map(indexedTuple->  {
if(!indexedTuple.getT2().getRequest().getCurrentSequenceValue().equals(indexedTuple.getT1()+1))
{
 throw new IllegalStateException("Orderingproblem at server at index"+indexedTuple.getT1());
};
return indexedTuple.getT2();
})
```

For a Flux of 4000 Elements I get each time the IllegalStateException at random positions for Example Error in Route send-message-client-to-server Orderingproblem at server at index 2175

In case I use less elements it seems to repeatedly work.

Comment: If you can make a reproduction in a single test file you should raise against rsocke-java.  Thanks for flagging.